# In Java, how do I override the class type of a variable in an inherited class?

Tags: java

In Java, how do I override the class type of a variable in an inherited class? For example:

```
class Parent {
  protected Object results;

  public Object getResults() { ... } 
}

class Child extends parent {

  public void operation() { 
  ... need to work on results as a HashMap
  ... results.put(resultKey, resultValue);
  ... I know it is possible to cast to HashMap everytime, but is there a better way?
  }

  public HashMap getResults() {
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Instead of  `Object`, can't you use `Map` as the return type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to achieve this:

```
class Parent<T> {
    protected T results;

    public T getResults() {
        return results;
    } 
}

class Child extends Parent<HashMap<String, Integer>> {

    public void operation() { 
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = getResults();
        ...
    }
}
```

Here I used key and value types of `String` and `Integer` as examples. You could also make `Child` generic on the key and value types if they vary:

```
class Child<K, V> extends Parent<HashMap<K, V>> { ... }
```

If you're wondering how to initialize the `results` field, that could take place in the constructor for example:

```
class Parent<T> {

    protected T results;

    Parent(T results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    ...
}

class Child<K, V> extends Parent<HashMap<K, V>> {

    Child() {
        super(new HashMap<K, V>());
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Some side notes:

It would be better for [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) if you made the `results` field `private`, especially since it has the accessor `getResults()` anyway. Also, consider making it `final` if it's not going to be reassigned.

Also, I'd recommend [programming to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) by using the `Map` type in your public declarations rather than `HashMap` specifically. Only reference the implementation type (`HashMap` in this case) when it's instantiated:

```
class Child<K, V> extends Parent<Map<K, V>> {

    Child() {
        super(new HashMap<K, V>());
    }

    ...
}
```